# QT Framework C++ how i access to progressBar from another class

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with accessing progressBar from another class.
Here's the method that does not work.
I have progress bar in UI(mainwindow.ui) with name progressBar.

```
void QtDownload::downloadProgress(qint64 recieved, qint64 total) {
   ui->progressBar->setMaximum(total);  
   ui->progressBar->setValue(recieved);
}
```

Here are all parts of the code:

**downloader.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-01-12T15:22:17
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT += network
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = downloader
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};


class QtDownload : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QtDownload();
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QString target;

    void setTarget(const QString& t);

private:


signals:
    void done();

public slots:
    void download();
    void downloadFinished(QNetworkReply* data);
    void downloadProgress(qint64 recieved, qint64 total);
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
    #include <QUrl>
    #include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
    #include <QFile>
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
    #include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
    #include <QByteArray>
    #include <QObject>

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {


        ui->setupUi(this);


        //  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
        QtDownload *dl =  new QtDownload();
       dl->setTarget( "http://media09.vbox7.com/s/21/21bbc2dca3r3634e3389.mp4");
       dl->download();
          //quit when the download is done.
        //  QObject::connect(&dl, SIGNAL(done()), &app, SLOT(quit()));

    }


    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }


    QtDownload::QtDownload() : QObject(0) {
        QObject::connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    }




    void QtDownload::setTarget(const QString &t) {
        this->target = t;
    }

    void QtDownload::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *data) {
        QFile localFile("C:/downloadedfile.mp4");
        if (!localFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
            return;
        const QByteArray sdata = data->readAll();
        localFile.write(sdata);
        qDebug() << sdata;
        localFile.close();

        emit done();
    }

    void QtDownload::download() {
        QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded(this->target.toLocal8Bit());
        QNetworkRequest request(url);
        QObject::connect(manager.get(request), SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));

    }

    void QtDownload::downloadProgress(qint64 recieved, qint64 total) {
        ui->progressBar->setMaximum(total);    // DOES NOT WORK
   ui->MainWindow.progressBar->setValue(recieved);  // DOES NOT WORK
    }
```

Comment: "does not work" wont lead you anywhere. How is it not working? You should start by reading the error message

Comment: Make `QtDownload::downloadProgress(quint64,quint64)` a signal instead of a slot. Then make a `MainWindow::downloadProgress(qint64 recieved, qint64 total)` slot. Connect the downloadProgress signal to the downloadProgress slot in `MainWindow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `slot` shouldn't be inside the `QtDownload`, it should be inside the `MainWindow`.

You should pass the `MainWindow` inside its constructor (just as a parent widget), and reuse this `MainWindow` in your connect, instead of uthing `this`.

**Edits in your QtDownload :**

Header

```
QtDownload(QObject* parent = 0); //Don't forget to make it in the source file

signals:
    void done();
    void downloadProgress(qint64 recieved, qint64 total);

public slots:
    void download();
    void downloadFinished(QNetworkReply* data);

private:
    MainWindow* parent; //Set it in the new constructor
```

Source

```
QtDownload::QtDownload(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    //The code that was initially inside QtDownload::QtDownload()
}

void QtDownload::download() {
    QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded(this->target.toLocal8Bit());
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QObject::connect(manager.get(request), SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), parent, SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));

}
```

**Edits in your MainWindow**

Header

```
public slots:
    void downloadProgress(qint64 recieved, qint64 total);
```

Source

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv); (Remove this line, it should be in the main.cpp
    QtDownload *dl =  new QtDownload(this); //Pass this as parameter
    dl->setTarget( "http://media09.vbox7.com/s/21/21bbc2dca3r3634e3389.mp4");
    dl->download();
    //quit when the download is done.
    //  QObject::connect(&dl, SIGNAL(done()), &app, SLOT(quit()));

}

void MainWindow::downloadProgress(qint64 recieved, qint64 total) {
    ui->progressBar->setMaximum(total);   
    ui->progressBar->setValue(recieved);
}
```

Comment: Ok but now i have this error :..\MyDownloader\mainwindow.cpp:21:41: error: no matching function for call to 'QtDownload::QtDownload()' QtDownload *dl = new QtDownload(); –

Comment: @How to See my updated answer, you forgot to pass the `MainWindow` as parameter in the `MainWindow` constructor

Comment: @Howto You did not fully read my answer. You did not fix the QtDownload constructor. I updated the answer with the code you have to change. I also edited the Header for QtDownload, so fix it too by replacing `MainWindow* parent` by `QObject* parent`